# Two dimentional array in AIDL

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, aidl

I am new to Android and `AIDLs`. Is it possible to have two dimentional array as a parameter passed in the functions of an `AIDL`?

For example something like:

```
int sayHello(in byte[][] langCountry);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you're not even allowed to pass a single-dimension array through AIDL.

You *are* allowed to use `List<something>`, where `something` is any other AIDL-compatible type. In theory therefore you could use `List<List<something>>`. However, whilst theoretically possible, I have found that this causes confusion for the AIDL compilers - you may have more luck.

For that reason I would suggest making a `Parcelable` object which encapsulates your 2D array: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html#PassingObjects